# How to swap values in an array by using Array.prototype.slice.call

Tags: javascript

It should be simple, but just can not wrap my mind why this is not working:

```
function swapValues() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    var temp = args[0];
    args[0] = args[1];
    args[1] = temp;
    return temp;
}

var arr = [1,2] 
swapValues(arr);
```

It should swap the values - but it does not.

Comment: what you want to do is augment the value of the array on the global scale.  Got ya.  Let me get a fiddle

Comment: Was your intention to swap the values (and mutate) the original array? Or to return a copy with the values swapped leaving the original untouched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arguments` is an object of the arguments, so your `args[0]` is `[1,2]` (the first argument), and `args[1]` is `undefined`.

You want something like this:

```
function swapValues() {
    var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)[0];
    var temp = arg[0];
    arg[0] = arg[1];
    arg[1] = temp;
    return arg;
}
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think that's quite what the OP wanted (although they are not very clear). My assumption for using `slice` is that they want to copy the array. You are modifying the original array because all you did is a shallow copy of `arguments`. I think they want `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[0])`

Comment: You may be right @MattBurland, but the way I read the question is it should swap the values. `slice` is commonly used on the `arguments` object to turn it into a real array.

Answer (score 0):

I have little changed your code but looks better this way. hope it helps.

```
function swapValues(arr) {
    var t = arr[0]; arr[0] = arr[1]; arr[1]=t;
    return arr;
}

var arr = [1,2] 
swapValues(arr);
```